# How to execute a function after the end of a cytoscape animation?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have a function that swaps the position of two nodes.

```
figlio.animate({
  position: posInizPadre,
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  }
}, {
  duration: 2000
});
padre.animate({
  position: posInizFiglio,
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
}, {
  duration: 2000
});
```

I'd like to execute a function after the padre.animate() function has ended.

I tried to use the complete property in animate() but it skips the animation and immediatly executes the function.
I even tried to use setTimeout but I get the same result, the function is immediatly executed and there is no animation

The animation works if i use it by itself

Comment: You are using jQuery?

Comment: No i'm only using javascript and cytoscape.js but if it helps i can add jquery

Comment: Sorry not familiar with that, looked like the jQuery animate function to me. You shouldn't implement a fill library just to make an animation. There will be someone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the **[complete](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.animate)** callback:

> complete: A function to call when the animation is done.

```
figlio.animate({
    position: posInizPadre,
    style: {
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    }
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    complete: function(){
        console.log('Animation complete');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked but if I put an already defined function instead of an anonymous function it doesn't seem to work. I'll use your solution that works fine.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I have done one example which is working fine with complete function

```
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.5.3/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #cy {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
    <script>
      var cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),
        elements: [
          { data: { id: 'a' } },
          { data: { id: 'b' } },
          {
            data: {
              id: 'ab',
              source: 'a',
              target: 'b'
            }
          }]
      });
      cy.animate({
   pan: { x: 50, y: 50 },
  zoom: 1,
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  complete:function(e){
      console.log('Complete');
  },
}, {
  duration: 2000
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```